# Add Subject to SENDMAIL.PHP file

Tags: php, forms, sendmail, contact-form

I have the following code that runs my contact form. The code works great but I would love to add a forced Subject to the email I receive since it currently comes up as "(no subject)". Any tips?

```
<?php
// Email Submit
// Note: filter_var() requires PHP >= 5.2.0
if ( isset($_POST['first_name']) && isset($_POST['last_name']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['project_name']) && isset($_POST['description'])  && filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ) {
    // detect & prevent header injections
    $test = "/(content-type|bcc:|cc:|to:)/i";
    foreach ( $_POST as $key => $val ) {
        if ( preg_match( $test, $val ) ) {
        exit;
    }
}

$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$project_name = $_POST['project_name'];
$description = $_POST['description'];

$message = "
First Name: $first_name \n
Last Name: $last_name\n
Project Name: $project_name\n
Description: $description
";

mail( "email@email.com", $_POST['date'], $message, "From:" . $_POST['email'] );
  //            ^
  //  Replace with your email
}
?>
```

Comment: What value did you want the subject line to contain?

Comment: Since you are new to StackOverflow: be sure to accept an answer by clicking on the checkbox if it resolves your issue.

Answer (score 2):

The second parameter of the mail function is the `$subject` parameter.
It could be that the value of your `$_POST['date']` is undefined leading to the recipient seeing '(no subject)'

Try changing the mail function to this:

```
mail( "email@email.com", 'New Message sent on ' . $_POST['date'], $message, "From:" . $_POST['email'] );
```

Read more here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

> **Usage** *bool mail ( string $to , string $subject , string $message [, string $additional_headers [, string $additional_parameters ]] )*

Answer (score 1):

Add the `require` attribute to the generated contact form (for the subject input field) html markup.  It will force the subject field to be filled out before you can submit it.

[Read a little more about the "required" attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp)